# Using SqueezeBox and PHP in an application?

Tags: php, mootools

I am developing an PHP/Mysql application whereby if the user enter a certain value, the results should be displayed to him in a Mootools SqueezeBox alert.

But all the usages of Squeeze I am seeing involve link-activated alerts i.e. when someone clicks a link, the Squeezebox alert appears.

How can it be as I mentioned?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you want to do is feasible. Use a text input that you can add information to, then use the value set to modify the link, and click the link. Something like:

```
$('userinput').addEvent('change', function(evt){
    var userValue = $('userinput').getProperty('value');
    var url = 'http://www.example.com/?property=' + encodeURI(userValue)
    $('linky').setProperty('href');
    $('linky').fireEvent('click');
});
```

With html like:

```
<input type="text" name="userinput" id="userinput" />
<a href="#" rel="boxed" id="linky">SqueezeBox Link</a>
```

Assuming [SqueezeBox](http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/) is adding `click` events, this should work.